# GStreamer volume plugin seems slow to react to volume property change

Tags: c++, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm currently building a small video player (and cutter) using GStreamer and Qt.
My pipeline is as follows :

```
|              | -> video  ->  | Queue | -----------------------------------------------------> | PlaySink |
| UriDecodeBin | -> audio1 ->  | Queue | -> | AudioConvert | -> | Volume | -> | AudioMixer | -> |          |
|              | -> audio2 ->  | Queue | -> | AudioConvert | -> | Volume | -> |            |
```

Volume is the plugin from https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/volume/index.html?gi-language=c
Playback is fine, pausing and seeking as well, but when I try to change the volume (while playing a video) using following call :

```
g_object_set(_volumes[track], "volume", value, NULL);
```

The change can be heard only around 1 second later, which feels extremely slow.

Is this latency to be expected for this plugin (and/or whole pipeline) ? 
If it isn't, how can I improve the latency of the change ?
If it is, is there any other plugin I can use to change the volume that would react faster ?

Answer (score 0):

*note : images inserted are quite wide, so open them in new tab if you want to zoom in*

The answer came by printing the full pipeline : delay was caused by  `playsink` element.

So, the old pipeline I used in the question looks like this :

[image]

We can see here that it the playsink created two queues, one for audio `aqueue` and one for video `vqueue`, and that those queues are using default buffering settings, allowing for up to one second of buffering, which was corresponding more or less to the delay I was experiencing when modifying volume parameters of the `volume` elements.

To solve the problem, I first looked into configuring the queues size for playsink, but it was unsuccessful, so I simply removed playsink from the pipeline, which now looks like this :

[image]

The audio queue `audioQueue` is setup to allow at most 50ms of buffering, which makes audio volume change quite reactive.

I didn't added a StreamSynchronizer as playsink uses. Synchronization seems to be fine. I'll try to figure out if it is needed or not in my case (single pipeline), and will update here if I find an answer.